# jquery select an element within parent

Tags: jquery, class, selector, parent

I have the following html:

```
<div>
  <div class="A">Some details</div<> 
  <div class="B">Some details</div<> 
  <div class="C">Some details</div<> 
</div>
```

What is the correct jquery syntax to select the div with class="C" starting from $(this) when "this" contains the class=A div?

Comment: `$(this).siblings('div.C')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(this).siblings('div.C');
```

Answer (score 0):

This shoudld do the trick.

```
$(this).parent().find('.C')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem

```
$(this).parent().find(">div.C")
```

OR

```
$(this).siblings(".C")
```